Why is JavaScript two-sided string literal interpolation not quadratic?
In JavaScript, why is this classic quadratic-append not O(n²)?
s = "";
for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  s = `( ${s} )`
};
console.log(s.length)

It's O(n) in both Firefox 124 and Chromium 123.
In Python, it's O(n²) as expected:
s = ""
for i in range(50_000):  # increase by 2x, gets 4x slower
  s = f"( {s} )"
print(len(s))

What is this magic, how are browsers cheating here?
Is that behaviour guaranteed by the ECMAScript spec?


What is this magic, how are browsers cheating here?

ropes

Is that behaviour guaranteed by the ECMAScript spec?

No, but every common JavaScript engine implements it, and new implementations pretty much have to because this was + is both the fastest and the easiest way to build up a string in major browsers and is therefore how most programs do it.
